# Damping of a pendulum through air and magnetic field (eddy currents)

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, classical-mechanics, electric-current, oscillators

So as part of a project, I am investigating how the damping coefficient changes as the surface area of a metal sheet increases. As it increases, intuitively so do the eddy currents generated and so the pendulum comes to rest in less time. So I measured the time taken for the pendulum to reach rest with damping through air and magnetic field, and then one data set with only damping through air resistance. How should I calculate the damping only due to the magnetic field? Which equation should I use?
There is $\theta = Ae^{-bt}cos(ft-c)$ where $c$ is the phase angle but is this correct and will it apply here?

The pendulum is a metal sheet which is oscillating in a magnetic field. The lateral face is perpendicular to the magnetic field lines. Hope that helps

Comment: Please use LaTeX to format equations. Please include a full description of the setup. It's not clear what your pendulum is and how it is damped.